# Remove docker images and containers that are taking disk space

Tags: docker, containers, disk, ps, data-cleaning

I've been using Docker for a while... I usually the command "docker run" to run containers. Today, I had the problem of saving data to disk on a database:

```
No space left on device
```

According to various documentation online, the solution is to use the following command:

`docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

However, it fails in a lot of entries... Is there a proper way to clean up containers and images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Docker supports the following command:

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -q --filter "dangling=true")
```

The command will properly remove the images... This is described at https://www.calazan.com/docker-cleanup-commands/, and some comments from http://jimhoskins.com/2013/07/27/remove-untagged-docker-images.html.